# Not able to connect to jenkins on localhost

Tags: jenkins

I installed Jenkins in a linux VM using .war file and
it showed "Jenkins is up and running". So I assume it is installed successfully.

Next, when I tried http://localhost:8080, it is showing "Connection Refused".

Also when I tried to do netstat, I am not able to see 8080 port.

So, I guess it is a firewall issue or are there any other settings I am missing.

Comment: are you trying to access jenkins from VM or host OS?

Comment: give  a try after disable/turn off firewall of VM

Comment: SO is for programming questions, and this isn't one. Superuser.com is probably more suitable for this... and I highly doubt that firewall would be blocking loopback.

Comment: If you are accessing from outside the VM, have you set up the port forwarding?

Comment: @Bhusak: I installed the jenkins inside the VM and I am trying to use the URL in my browser.. So ideally, you can say outside the VM.. Also, I tried using curl inside the VM and it showed the same connection refused.

Comment: @yong: Even I suspect so, but to turn the firewall off I need to check with our network team. So, wanted to check with experts like you first

Comment: @Sanchez: Can you kindly throw some more light on port forwarding..I am not sure about it.

Comment: what's the OS of you VM?  Ubuntn, Centos, Redhat?  You can google how to turn off firewall on that OS. And you work in a VM I don't think you nee to check with your network team.

Comment: @bimalpatel It depends on the software used for running your VM. Could you please provide some info about your scenario?